# Second category set with empty interior in $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$

Tags: general-topology, baire-category, cantor-set

Consider the space $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$ endowed with the product topology (of the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$).

> **Question.** Does there exist a second category set $S\subseteq X$ with empty interior?

Comment: Hint: $X$ is a separable space.

Comment: In addition to the hint from Daniel Fischer,  $X$ is also homeomorphic to the Cantor set, which is an uncountable complete metric space with no  countable neighborhoods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is compact metrisable so second category in itself. If $D$ is countable and dense then $S=X\setminus D$ is second category and has empty interior.